# I can fly without wings

Tags: riddle

I can fly without wings, 
only carried by the wind.
I am heavier when empty,
the bigger I am, the more I can carry.

What am I ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think you are a:

> Helium balloon or a hot air balloon.
>
>  They fly (float) and have no propulsion, so get carried by wind
>  Since helium and hot air reduce the weight, they are heavier when empty and when bigger, they have more helium and hot air and can lift more.

Comment: This isn't correct - Helium and hot air have a lower density than air or fabric/wood/whatever your balloon is built out of. This means filling the balloon with those gases reduces its overall density, allowing it to fly.
It is however lighter when not filled.

Comment: I bet this is the correct answer :) @jazzpi , when the ballon is empty, it is heavier, that's why it falls on the ground. This answer makes sense.

Comment: @zlobi.wan.kenobi This isn't correct. When the balloon is full of hot air, it's less dense than air, so it likes to ascend. It's definitely heavier than when it's empty! This answer just doesn't work out really, unfortunately.

Comment: A filled balloon has more mass, less density, and is perceived to be "lighter" due to buoyancy. So, it really depends on what you're going for with weight. Generally, it's the force exerted on a scale under normal conditions.

Comment: Well said @JonTheMon . Still, this is a riddle, so the physics behind is not so important as the end result. Therefore, the answer to the riddle makes sense for me.

Comment: The confusion here comes from weight vs mass. Weight is the apparent  downward force, where as mass is the amount of 'stuff' that makes it up. A balloon is heavier when empty, yet it is less 'massive' when empty.

Comment: @kadreal the confusion isn't about weight and mass, it's about weight and bouyancy.
An object's weight is the force that object exerts in a downward direction as a result of its mass.
Hot air balloons don't float because they have a low weight. They float because the downward force of their weight is less than the upward force exerted on the balloon by the mass of the air that it displaces.

Comment: Interesting discussion. Going back to the formula helped decide this for me: $F=ma$, or $W=mg$ in the case of weight and gravity. Given constant $g$, weight is proportional to mass. By the way, physics aside, JonTheMon's answer looks good.

Answer (score 18):

First timer here.  I think you could be:

> A promise.

I can fly without wings, 
only carried by the wind.

> A "promise in the wind".  I think it means the promise is the only thing you have, the promise-maker might be away or unreachable and all that's left is the promise itself.

I am heavier when empty,

> The weight of an empty promise...

the bigger I am, the more I can carry.

> ...contrasted with what a big promise can *carry*.  "Her hopes and dreams *ride on* the promise that one day her father would return."

Comment: Ooo deep man. Way deep. Got me thinking

Answer (score 4):

I would say JonTheMon's answer is more accurate but here's my attempt:  You are a

> Cloud

I can fly without wings, only carried by the wind.

> Cloud 'fly' without wings but move by the wind

I am heavier when empty

> Heavy "rain" from the cloud until it's 'empty'

the bigger I am, the more I can carry.

> Bigger cloud carries more liquid droplets

Comment: I was thinking cloud at first, but the heavier when empty doesn't fit.  As you mention, the water makes it heavier 'until it's empty'.  When it's empty it's not heavier.

Answer (score 2):

**Second Guess**

> Paper

I can fly without wings

> Paper doesn't have wings. Yet it glides along the wind.

only carried by the wind

> Paper can get carried by wind.

I am heavier when empty

> Darn! I don't know...

the bigger I am, the more I carry

> A blgger piece of paper contains more information than a smaller piece of paper

Original Guess

I think it is

> words

I can fly without wings,

> "Words fly all over the place"?

only carried by the wind.

> Words are, when spoken,sound: carried by wind.

I am heavier when empty,
the bigger I am, the more I can carry.

> Big words/phrases carry more information.

Comment: The second guess makes sense

Answer (score 2):

How about:

> Time

I can fly without wings

> Time can 'fly' but has no wings

only carried by the wind

> Here 'wind' could refer not to moving air, but to the 'winding up' of a clock. Could also perhaps be a reference to the 'Winds of Time'...

I am heavier when empty

> Empty time tends to drag heavily, due to boredom

the bigger I am, the more I carry

> The more time you have, the more you can fit into it

Answer (score 1):

> A "by-the-wind sailor" type jellyfish: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velella

No wings, blown by the wind

> Self explanatory

Heavier when empty

> Well, it wouldn't be empty (of water) unless it was dead and removed from the sea, at which point it would be true.

The bigger I am, the more I can carry

> I guess it can carry more food/water.  This line is the main reason I'm not so sure about this answer.

This is my first time here; go easy on me!

Comment: Is it "blown by the wind" though, if it lives on the water?

Comment: Aren't boats blown by the wind?

Comment: Boats have sails; does this jellyfish have some sort of sail? (I'm not saying you're wrong, just that maybe you should explain the first line a little more!)

Comment: Perhaps if you clicked on the link in the first line of my answer, all would become a little clearer?

Comment: I did click on it and skimmed through the article. Having now read it a little more closely, I found the line "the small rigid sail projects into the air and catches the wind". But be warned: a lot of people aren't going to be interested enough to do that, and they may DV your answer! +1 from me though - and welcome to Puzzling.SE btw! :-)

Answer (score 0):

> A parachute.
>  It "flies" on wind power alone, and can carry heavier loads as its surface area increases.

But that doesn't quite seem to fit the third line.

Answer (score 0):

> You are **the fuel tank of a cargo helicopter**.

[image]

1. Rotors are airfoils, but they're not wings.
2. Accelerated air is wind.  Downwardly accelerated air creates lift.
3. When the fuel tank becomes empty, the helicopter suddenly becomes much heavier.
4. The bigger the tank, the more you can carry...

Comment: How does the helicopter become heavier when the tank is empty?

Comment: @jazzpi - Weight = mass * acceleration due to gravity.  When fuel is exhausted, the engine stops running, the rotor disc stops producing lift to offset gravity, and the weight of the aircraft increases.  The *mass* never changes, but the weight does.

Comment: As you said, $W = m g$, not $W = m a$. Whilst a helicopter's rotors can provide acceleration opposite to $g$ so that $a$ = 0, they don't actually affect $g$ so they don't affect the weight.